# Given $A \times B$ and $C \times D$ are disjoint sets. Then prove either $A$ and $C$ are disjoint or $B,D$ are disjoint.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Given $A \times B$ and $C \times D$ are disjoint sets. Then prove either $A$ and $C$ are disjoint or $B,D$ are disjoint. '

Let this is of type that if $p \implies q \lor r$. To prove this i assume $\lnot q$ and tries to prove r. So negating A,C are disjoint i get

$ \exists x(x \in A \implies x \in C) $. (There can be more than one values for x's) Lets call this  x as $a_1$. So $a_1 \in A$ AND $a_1 \in C$. Also we have $A \times B$ and $C \times D$ are disjoint sets. Now i have to prove that $ \forall x (x \in B \implies x \notin D)$. So let $x \in B$. So $(a_1 , x ) \in A \times B $. Since $A \times B$ and $C \times D$ are disjoint. So either $a_1 \notin C$ or $x \notin D$. So finally i get $x \notin D$.

I am not confident about my proof though. Please suggest
Thanks

Comment: Seems good, though all the logical formalism is a bit unecessary in my opinion. It suffices to say simply that, upon the assumption that there exists $x \in A \cap C$ then if $y \in B \cap D$, we have $(x,y) \in A \times B \cap C \times D$, a contradiction.

Comment: I think in this case is easier to assume the full negation of $q\vee r$, remembering that $\neg (q\vee r)=\neg q \wedge \neg r$. In this case $q\vee r$ is the statement "$A,C$ are disjoint or $B,D$ are disjoint", and its negation would be $A,C$ are not disjoint and $B,D$ are not disjoint. Hence, there are elements $x\in A\cap C$ and $y\in B\cap D$. Then, $x$ belongs to both $A$ and $C$, and $y$ belongs to both $B$ and $D$, obtaining that $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cap (C\times D)$

Comment: @leibnewtz Which method have you used?

Comment: @Wore Thanks mate

Comment: @J.Deff I simply rewrote your argument using a bit simpler language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of limiting yourself to $\lnot q$ it is easier to prove the contrapositive : $\lnot q\land\lnot r\implies \lnot p$

If $A,C$ and $B,D$ are not disjoint then $\exists a\in A\cap C$ and $\exists b\in B\cap D$.

Then $(a,b)$ is common to $A\times B$ and $C\times D$.